# Query regarding bellman ford

Tags: c++, graph-theory, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I have been studying Bellman Ford algorithm lately. I have a doubt that if a negative weight cycle in a directed graph reachable from source vertex ,then shortest does not exist for all nodes or for some nodes.This is mine implementation of bellman ford.

```
 //O(VE)
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
#define sl(n) scanf("%lld",&n)
#define pl(n) printf("%lld",n)
#define MOD 1000000007
#define inf 1e18
#define rep(i,n) for(i=0;i<n;i++)
#define mset(x,v) memset(x, v, sizeof(x))
vector<ll>t,s;
ll nodes, edges;

void bellman_ford(vector<pair<ll,ll> >mp[],ll src){
ll i,j;
for(i=1;i<=nodes;i++){
t[i]=inf;
}
t[src]=0;

vector<pair<ll,ll> > :: iterator it;

for(i=1;i<nodes;i++){//O(nodes-1) times
    for(j=1;j<=nodes;j++){//O(edges)
        if(t[j]!=inf)
        for(it=mp[j].begin();it!=mp[j].end();it++)
        t[it->first]=min(t[j]+it->second,t[it->first]);
    }
}

bool flag=1;
for(j=1;j<=nodes;j++){//detecting negative cycles
    for(it=mp[j].begin();it!=mp[j].end();it++)
    if(t[j]+it->second < t[it->first])
        {
            flag=0;break;
        }

}

if(flag==0)
for(j=1;j<=nodes;j++){//assigning all shortest paths to be -inf
        t[j]=-inf;
}


}


int main()
{
ll x, y, wt,i;
sl(nodes);
sl(edges);
vector<pair<ll,ll> >mp[nodes+1];//1 based indexing of nodes
t.resize(nodes+1);

rep(i,edges){
sl(x);sl(y);sl(wt);
mp[x].push_back(make_pair(y,wt));
mp[y].push_back(make_pair(x,wt));
}

ll src;sl(src);
bellman_ford(mp,src);


for(i=1;i<=nodes;i++)
cout<<i<<" "<<t[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If I understood the initial part correctly, you are uncertain about the definition of "shortest path". If it is possible to go from a source vertex `s` to a terminal vertex `t` in such a way that the path contains a cycle of negative length, this cycle can be repeated arbitrarily often, resulting in an arbitrarily small distance. In a certain sense, this means that there is no "shortest" path between `s` and `t`.

Comment: @Codor How will we check in bellman ford that the path from s to t contain negative cycle. Please check my code.

Comment: I posted an answer of what i think was your question. However. You should make clear what exeactly you want to know or what your problem is. Otherwise there is no way to make an specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, AFAIK there is no shortest path in a network, if the network contains a negative cycle, because it would go to infinity.
BellmanFord works only if there is no negativ cycle and is able to find such, if they exists.
Your C++ is a little bit scary, however. It is proven, that after

```
for(i=1;i<nodes;i++){//O(nodes-1) times
for(j=1;j<=nodes;j++){//O(edges)
    if(t[j]!=inf)
    for(it=mp[j].begin();it!=mp[j].end();it++)
    t[it->first]=min(t[j]+it->second,t[it->first]);
}
}
```

the algorithm terminates, if there is no negative cycle (could althoug terminate earlier).

If there is a edge with t[j]+it->second < t[it->first] after this loop, then there is a negative cycle.
If this was your question, then you were probably in the wrong forum.
My explenation work only, if your code is a correct implementation.